# How should I format my XML using XSLT...variables? loops?

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT and have to use version 1.0 with XPath 1.0 and would appreciate your help on this.  I have tried different ways and although I have gotten close to the solution, I am still missing something.  I've tried variables, but those don't work out since you can't reuse them and I can't create a meaningful array in XML/XPath 1.  I've tried loops, but I don't want the column headers repeated every time...

About the format of the output/data:
Its basically a checklist pertaining to some number of individuals (there are only two in this example...could be 1 or more).

For the first customer - The header is basically 'Applicant:' followed by the Applicant's name in the first column and 'Status' in the second. On the next line is the item to check in the first column and the status in the second column.  Note that the item to check is the same for both individuals (in this example), but the status is different.

This pattern repeats for some number of customers (again there are 2 here...but could be any number).  Below I've provided a small subset of the applicable XML and XSLT files that I am using.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LendingChecklistReport>
  <LoanHdr>
  ...
  </LoanHdr>
  <ChecklistItems>
    <Item>
      <ChecklistType>SomeListType</ChecklistType>
      <ChecklistSubTypeDesc>Alpha</ChecklistSubTypeDesc>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <ChecklistType>Applicant</ChecklistType>
      <ChecklistSubTypeDesc>Cosmo Kramer</ChecklistSubTypeDesc>
      <ItemDescription>Item to Check1</ItemDescription>
      <Status>Pending</Status>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <ChecklistType>Applicant</ChecklistType>
      <ChecklistSubTypeDesc>Adolph Credco</ChecklistSubTypeDesc>
      <ItemDescription>Item to Check1</ItemDescription>
      <Status>Waived</Status>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <ChecklistType>Applicant</ChecklistType>
      <ChecklistSubTypeDesc>Cosmo Kramer</ChecklistSubTypeDesc>
      <ItemDescription>Item to Check2</ItemDescription>
      <Status>In Progress</Status>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <ChecklistType>Applicant</ChecklistType>
      <ChecklistSubTypeDesc>Adolph Credco</ChecklistSubTypeDesc>
      <ItemDescription>Item to Check2</ItemDescription>
      <Status>Holding</Status>
    </Item>
    ....
  </ChecklistItems>
```

And here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:decimal-format name="us" decimal-separator='.' grouping-separator=',' />
  <xsl:param name="CurrentDate"/>

  <!--<xsl:variable name="myVArray">
    A
    B
    C
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="ApplicantNames" select="/*/Applicant" />-->


  <xsl:template match="/LendingChecklistReport">

    <!--myVArray:
    <xsl:value-of select="$myVArray[1]"/>

    ApplicantNames:
    <xsl:value-of select="$ApplicantNames[1]"/>-->

    <table style="width: 800px; padding: 0px; border: solid 0px blue;" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td class="Logo">logo</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="Title">
          Document Checklist
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <!-- Header table -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="LoanHdr" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="Separator"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <!-- Applicants table -->
          <span class="Label">Applicants</span>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Applicants" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="Separator"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>

          <!-- Checklist table -->
          <span class="Label">Checklist Items</span>
          <table class="Table">
            <!--<xsl:for-each select="Applicants/Applicant">
            <xsl:sort select="ChecklistSubTypeDesc"/>

              <tr>
                <td class="ChecklistType, ColumnHeader" style="width: 50%">
                  Applicant: <xsl:value-of select="ApplicantName" />
                </td>
                <td class="ColumnHeader" style="text-align: center; width: 10%">Status</td>
                <td class="ColumnHeader" style="text-align: center; width: 20%">Assigned To</td>
                <td class="ColumnHeader" style="text-align: center; width: 20%">Due</td>
              </tr>

          <xsl:for-each select="/LendingChecklistReport/ChecklistItems/Item[ChecklistType = 'B']">
              <xsl:sort select="ChecklistSubTypeDesc"/>
                <tr>
                  <td style="color: red">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ItemDescription" />
                    <xsl:for-each select="Response">
                      <br />
                      <span class="Hint" style="margin-left: 10px">
                        Response: <xsl:value-of select="." />
                      </span>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Status" />
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center">
                    <xsl:value-of select="AssignedTo" />
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center">
                    <xsl:value-of select="DueBy" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>

              <tr>
                <td class="Separator"></td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>-->


            <tr>
              <td class="ChecklistType, ColumnHeader" style="width: 50%">
                Applicant:
              </td>
              <td class="ColumnHeader" style="text-align: center; width: 10%">Status</td>
              <td class="ColumnHeader" style="text-align: center; width: 20%">Assigned To</td>
              <td class="ColumnHeader" style="text-align: center; width: 20%">Due</td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="ChecklistItems/Item[ChecklistType = 'B']">
              <xsl:sort select="ChecklistSubTypeDesc"/>
              <tr>
                <td style="color: red">
              <xsl:value-of select="ChecklistSubTypeDesc" />: <xsl:value-of select="ItemDescription" />
                  <xsl:for-each select="Response">
                    <br />
                    <span class="Hint" style="margin-left: 10px">
                      Response: <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </span>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                  <xsl:value-of select="Status" />
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                  <xsl:value-of select="AssignedTo" />
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                  <xsl:value-of select="DueBy" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <tr>
              <td class="ChecklistType, ColumnHeader" style="width: 50%">Collateral</td>
              <td class="ColumnHeader" style="text-align: center; width: 10%">Status</td>
              <td class="ColumnHeader" style="text-align: center; width: 20%">Assigned To</td>
              <td class="ColumnHeader" style="text-align: center; width: 20%">Due</td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ChecklistItems/Item[ChecklistType = 'C']" />

            <tr>
              <td class="Separator"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="ChecklistType, ColumnHeader" style="width: 50%">Loan</td>
              <td class="ColumnHeader" style="text-align: center; width: 10%">Status</td>
              <td class="ColumnHeader" style="text-align: center; width: 20%">Assigned To</td>
              <td class="ColumnHeader" style="text-align: center; width: 20%">Due</td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ChecklistItems/Item[ChecklistType = 'L']" />
          </table>

        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="Separator"></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </xsl:template>


  <!-- Header table -->
  <xsl:template match="LoanHdr">
    ...
  </xsl:template>


  <!-- Applicants table -->
  <xsl:template match="Applicants">
    <table class="Table">
      <tr>
        <td class="ColumnHeader">Name</td>
        <td class="ColumnHeader">Type</td>
      </tr>

      <xsl:for-each select="Applicant">
        <xsl:sort select="ApplicantName"/>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="ApplicantName" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Relationship" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>


  <!-- Applicants detail -->
  <xsl:template match="/LendingChecklistReport/ChecklistItems/Item[ChecklistType = 'B']">
    <!--<xsl:sort select="ChecklistType"/>-->
    <tr>
      <td style="color: red">
        <xsl:value-of select="ItemDescription" />
        <xsl:for-each select="Response">
          <br />
          <span class="Hint" style="margin-left: 10px">
            Response: <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </span>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center">
        <xsl:value-of select="Status" />
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center">
        <xsl:value-of select="AssignedTo" />
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center">
        <xsl:value-of select="DueBy" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
Applicant: Cosmo Kramer              Status
Item to Check1                       Pending
Item to Check2                       In Progress

Applicant: Adolph Credco             Status
Item to Check1                       Waived
Item to Check2                       Holding
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a more meaningful title. "How do I get this XSLT to work" will probably get your question downvoted and closed. Describe what your actual problem is. Grouping nodes? Formatting output? And don't forget to include your XSLT!

Comment: I suggest you start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: You haven't shown us your XSLT code.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].  You are expected to attempt a solution before posting and ask a specific question.  As it stands, your question is more like "Please do this work for me".

Comment: @helderdarocha: Sorry, I will modify the title to make it more specific.  Also, I didn't include the XSLT since it doesn't work...so what's the use?  There is something that I am not doing correctly so the XSLT that I've come up with will only confuse the issue.  I did add a description (call it pseudocode...which I have seen other people do as well.

Comment: @Jim Garrison: You are right and I did not want this question to sound like a hand-out.  I did say that I have tried many different ways to solve the issue.  I guess I could have copied and pasted a block of code, but that would have just cluttered the problem and prolonged the pain.  I did read through both of those links before I posted and thought that my post exhibited all of the required traits.

Comment: @Michael.hor257k: Thank you for the link.  I was able to correctly formatt my output after looking through that link and mg_kedzie's solution below.  Makes me feel not quite so inept since I guess my issue was a little complicated and hardly anyone could solve it =)

Comment: Just FYI, I have voted down mg_kedzie's solution below, because it uses the very method described as "very inefficient" in Jeni Tennison's article. IMHO, you should mark your own answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="Applicants" use="ChecklistSubTypeDesc" match="Item"/>

<xsl:template match="ChecklistItems">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[ChecklistType='Applicant']"/>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item">
      <xsl:variable name="currentName" select="ChecklistSubTypeDesc"/>
     <xsl:if test="not(following::Item/ChecklistSubTypeDesc[text() = $currentName])">
     <xsl:value-of select="ChecklistType"/>: <xsl:value-of select="$currentName"/><xsl:text>     </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="Status/name()"/>
     <xsl:for-each select="key('Applicants',$currentName)"><xsl:text>
     </xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="ItemDescription"/><xsl:text>    </xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="Status"/>

     </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:if><xsl:text>

     </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you - I've been busy, but I'll be able to look at and implement the solution hopefully pretty soon

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I was able to use your example and the example link above to correctly format my code.  I had never used the key element before or any of the more advanced conditions that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx again for the help...after the answer and link provided, I was able to come up with a solution.  Using the same XML provided, here is the XSLT that I used:

```
<xsl:key name="ApplicantNameCollection" match="/LendingChecklistReport/ChecklistItems/Item" use="ChecklistSubTypeDesc" />

<xsl:template match="/LendingChecklistReport">
  <xsl:for-each select="ChecklistItems">

    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="ChecklistItems/Item[ChecklistType='Applicant'][count(. | key('ApplicantNameCollection', ChecklistSubTypeDesc)[1]) = 1]">

        <tr>
          <td>Applicant: <xsl:value-of select="ChecklistSubTypeDesc" /></td>
          <td>Status</td>
        </tr>

        <xsl:for-each select="key('ApplicantNameCollection', ChecklistSubTypeDesc)">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="ItemDescription" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Status" /></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <tr>
          <td class="Separator"></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>

  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```